# I dont get my Date in the exact Format while using the date-fns library?

Tags: reactjs, date, date-fns

I am using date-fns Library to format my date, I am using ReactJS, and here is my code :

```
// dateOperation is a date

console.log("date Original :");
console.log(dateOperation);

item.annee = dateOperation.getFullYear();
console.log("date FULL YEAR :");
console.log(item.annee);

item.dateOperation = format(dateOperation, "DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log("date operation :");
console.log(item.dateOperation);
```

I will share the results I get while writing that code :

```
date Original :
14 Fri Jul 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
date FULL YEAR :
2018
date operation :
187/07/2018
```

I dont want that format :

```
187/07/2018
```

But this one :

```
06/07/2018
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick check and I see dateFns is giving proper results. BTW I have used cdn instead of npm module.
Below is the example

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let dateOperation = new Date()
    let item={}
    item.annee = dateOperation.getFullYear();
    console.log("date FULL YEARs s :");
    console.log(item.annee);

    item.dateOperation =  dateFns.format(dateOperation, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    console.log("date operations :");
    console.log(item.dateOperation);

    return <div>Hello, Please see console</div>;
  }
}

React.render(<HelloMessage />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: It didnt gave propper results to me, I changed "DD" and I wrote "dd" instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check your actual code carefully.  You probably have `DDD/MM/YYYY` instead of `DD/MM/YYYY` that you showed here.

- `DD` gives you the two-digit day of the month
- `DDD` gives you the day of the *year*

Comment: Careful, formatting tokens are case sensitive.  `dd` is different than `DD`.  See https://date-fns.org/docs/format

Comment: Matt Johnson : Well, Some one on github told me that there were an update in this library and gave me that answer and it worked, the problem is that DD gave me the day of the year not the month .. Thank you anyway Sir. have a great day.